# mel command ('rendersequence;') is not working whille trying to open maya from command line

Tags: python, maya, mel, maya-api

So basically I am trying to open maya from command line using subprocess in python and executing a python script (.py) file like below:

```
command = [
        "C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2020/bin/maya.exe",
        '-command',
        'python("exec('python script path")'
    ]
```

from my script everything is working fine like maya is opening and as well the file except one command for example:

```
mel.eval('renderSequenceOptionsWindow;')
mel.eval('optionMenuGrp -e -v "{}" renderSequenceCameraList;'.format(facial_cam_node))
mel.eval('renderSequenceCurrentCameraChanged();')
mel.eval('renderSequence;')
```

I have these commands first three are working fine except the last one , the issue is I am not getting an error as well, its like Maya is not even considering this command from the script.

- Here <`facial_cam_node`> is the camera I'll be using to render images.

And the weird part is on the same opened Maya session ( which I opened from command line), when I am running this command back again in script editor then its rendering as well, its just not happening in the automated workflow.

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: It's possible that not all commands e.g. UI commands are available direclty after opening maya. Try to use the `evalDeferred()` command to see if this is the reason.

Comment: Hey thanks alot it worked for me , I used it earlier but I was running after a function call, this time i just put it there in the subprocess command itself and it worked for me.